# Sending invitation mail and receiving response with receiver's email address

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I am sending an invitation message through email for two person, with two link buttons (Approve/Reject) options.

Now, How do I know who has clicked on **Approve** button? So I can send an extra mail for the one who clicked on **Approve** button.

I am sending the mail through PHP code.

The links somehow looks like below

For Approve Button
http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=1

For Reject Button
http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=0

I am asking this to find a perfect idea or solution!

Comment: Append the email address of the person as an additional URL parameter …? (Plus perhaps a hash of the email and a secret, so that you can verify the link was genuine by checking the hash on the server side, so that no one can approve for someone else by simply changing the email parameter value.)

Comment: Thanks for useful comment, I am sending one message to multiple email address at once.

Comment: @MȍhǟmmǟdȘamȋm no, you need to send unique hash for each email. cause, it will consolidation multiple times hash check.

Comment: _“I am sending one message to multiple email address at once”_ - well that can’t work for what you want here. In that case, you could only make that link point to a website where the user has to manually enter their email address into a form and submit it then. If you don’t want such an extra step, then you need to send an individual mail to each recipient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cookies or sessions if you are trying to keep track of user
if they are not your user

For example, you are sending them in an email approve and reject button
then make the url like this

For Approve Button [http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=1&id=HASH of ID](http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=1&id=HASH%20of%20ID)

For Reject Button [http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=0&id=HASH OF ID](http://192.198.0.0/webApp/process.php?response=0&id=HASH%20OF%20ID)

Make a DB when you send an email for each email sent take their email id and save with an ID
HASH OF ID = that ID of Email Sent!

Then when ever the Approve button click get id from $_GET search it in DB send email again!

Comment: Thanks for the great Idea, but I am sending one email to multiple email addresses at once.

Comment: Then you have to send a tracking id or hash id for each url you send as Approve button as many email marketing company send email to multiple email address but they send unique tracking id to each address and unique click url id!
Other then it i don't think you can get a way!